# Проблема в работе с переменными в отдельном классе C#

Tags: c#, классы

возникла проблема. Есть часть кода а-ля свитч-кейс:

```
case 2: //Задание 2
Console.Clear();
Start1A2:
Console.WriteLine("Введите трехзначное число");
try
{
OneATwo.x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (FormatException)
{
Console.WriteLine($"{OneATwo.Calculate()}");
goto Start1A2;
}
if (OneATwo.output == "Число не удовлетворяет условию задачи")
{
Console.WriteLine("no");
Console.WriteLine(OneATwo.Calculate());
goto Start1A2;
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("yes");
Console.WriteLine($"{OneATwo.x},{OneATwo.xdup},{OneATwo.x100},{OneATwo.x10},{OneATwo.x1},{OneATwo.sum}");
Console.WriteLine(OneATwo.Calculate());
}
break;
```

есть класс в отдельном файле:

```
class OneATwo
    {
        public static double x;
        public static double xdup;
        public static double x100;
        public static double x10;
        public static double x1;
        public static double sum;
        public static string output;
        public static string Calculate()
        {
            xdup = x;
            x100 = x % 100;
            x = x - x100 * 100;
            x10 = x % 10;
            x1 = x - x10 * 10;
            sum = x100 + x10 + x1;
            if (xdup >= 100 && xdup <= 999)
            {
                if (Math.IEEERemainder(sum, 3) == 0)
                {
                    output = $"Число {xdup} делится на 3 без остатка";
                }
                else
                {
                    output = $"Число {xdup} не делится на 3 без остатка";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                output = "Некорректно введены данные";
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
```

Но, при сборке, код собирается, но при выборе данного задания и ввода 123, выдаёт это:
[image: результат выполнения кейса, и класса примотанного к кейсу]

Можете подсказать, почему значение 123 не передаётся другим переменным?
P.S: Автор идиот, забыл написать что этот код вообще делает. А делает он это[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вводная переменная только одна, и это x = 123. xdup как костыль для выведения x в ответе. x100 = цифра, отвечающая за количество сотен. x10 и x1 по аналогии с x100. sum сумма цифр трёхзначного числа(для 123 это 6)

Comment: Не по теме, но: старайтесь не использовать `goto`. Чаще всего он делает код более запутанным, препятствует отладке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сделали неправльно всё, что можно. Вы запутались сами в своем коде. И вот причны этому:

1. `goto` уже не нужно. Не используйте его. Оно усложняет чтение кода
2. `catch (FormatException) ... Console.WriteLine($"{OneATwo.Calculate()}");`  вы пытаетесь вычислить что то, когда у вас ввод не удался
3. `Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())` для того, чтобы понять, делится ди число нацело, надо оперировать целыми числами. Дробные числа (числа с ненулевой дроной частью) не делятся нацело.
4. `public static double x;` статические поля - плохая практика, они учеличивают сложность кода. Не используйте их без необходимости
5. `public static double x100;` научитесь работать с локальными переменными

Вы забываете вызывать `Calculate()` в нужных местах.

Как можно решить проще?

Пишем функцию для считывания числа

```
public int ReadNUmber(){
    int result;
    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result)){
        Console.WriteLine("Число введено неверно. Попробуйте ещё раз.а");       
    }
    return result;  
}
```

Функцию для валидации

```
public bool IsValid(int  number){
    return number >= 100 && number <= 999;
}
```

Функцию для проверки делимости

```
public bool CanDivideBy3(int number){
    int sum = 0;
    while(number > 0)
    {
        sum += number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Сумма цифр {sum}");
    return sum % 3 == 0;    
}
```

Собираем всё вместе

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите трехзначное число");
var number = ReadNUmber();
if (!IsValid(number)){
    Console.WriteLine("Некорректно введены данные");
    return;
}

if (CanDivideBy3(number)){
    Console.WriteLine($"Число {number} делится на 3 без остатка");
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine($"Число {number} НЕ делится на 3 без остатка");
}
```

Вот и всё.

Comment: Окей, а как поступить, если всю логику нужно вынести в отдельный класс, для дальнейшего создания модульных тестов? Просто без static у меня отказывается собираться код. При использовании static что-то видимо ломается и while в ReadNumber не выполняет вложенный код

Comment: @ИннокентийМихайлов Я Вам уже сказал, что у Вас "ломается".

Comment: @ИннокентийМихайлов вы пытаетесь считывать с консоли в модульном тесте? Или в чем конкретно проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта строчка

```
x = x - 100 * 100;
```

что делает?

---

Остальные строчки я тоже не понимаю. Что, например, Вы ожидаете получить в переменной `x100`? Подозреваю, что `1`.  Но нет.

Количество сотен в целом числе находится так:

```
hundreds = x / 100;
```

Цифра в разряде сотен находится так:

```
hundreds = (x % 1000) / 100;
```

---

Хорошо. Давайте так.

```
int x = 123;

int x100 = x % 100;
x = x - x100 * 100;
```

Какое сейчас число в `x`? (Напишу через пять минут.)

---

К проблеме нулевых значений переменных.

Поменяйте местами строчки

```
Console.WriteLine($"{OneATwo.x},{OneATwo.xdup},{OneATwo.x100},{OneATwo.x10},{OneATwo.x1},{OneATwo.sum}");
Console.WriteLine(OneATwo.Calculate());
```

---

Посмотрите на фрагменты:

```
output = "Некорректно введены данные";

...

if (OneATwo.output == "Число не удовлетворяет условию задачи")
```

Будет когда-нибудь `output` равен тому, с чем Вы его сравниваете?

Comment: Опечатка, а функционал расписал в ps

Comment: Вот только проблема адекватного присваивания значений аргументам всё равно имеет место быть

Comment: @ИннокентийМихайлов Какое присваивание? Посчитайте на бумажке что Вы делаете.

Comment: всё равно выдаёт 0 во всех переменных кроме x

Comment: @ИннокентийМихайлов Мне плохо сквозь монитор виден Ваш код. Прежде чем писать код, убедитесь, что Вы можете задачу без компьютера, на листке бумаги. Минус ставлю Вам.

Comment: До правки это был скорее вопрос к автору вопроса. Теперь всё нормально.